# understanding JS6 template literals for making dynamic CSS classNames

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

After several courses we got introduced to React. The overall used system is a localhost npm Server, with installed React. Later we will install Mongo and Express.

Topic of the lesson is, some kind of Webshop with 2 tabs: Items and Cart in the Navbar and automatic filled list either with the shop items, or the chosen user Cart items.

The Navbar in the header consists of 2 <li-<button "Items"  / "Cart" elements. These elements shall earn their className dynamically, based on the global hook const activeTab. Syntax is following:

```
 const Nav = ({activeTab, onTabChange}) => {
    const itemClass = tabName => 
        `App-nav-item ${ 
            activeTab === tabName ? 'selected': '' 
        }`;
    return (
    <nav className="App-nav">
        <ul>
            <li className={itemClass('items')}>

###
```

I understand, that itemClass is a template literal of the string 'App-nav-item' and the String 'selected' or ''. Results should be App-nav-itemselected  or App-nav-item

But the result is App-nav-item.selected !  Why? In CSS I have to adress App-nav-item.selected, I don't understand that.

Comment: Using some of the formatting tools (e.g. code formatting for class names and CSS selectors) would make this question considerably easier to read.

Comment: "*`itemClass` is a template literal of the string …*" - no, `itemClass` is a function taking a `tabName` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Results should be App-nav-itemselected or App-nav-item

No. There is a space between `App-nav-item` and `${...}`. It will be `App-nav-item selected` or `App-nav-item`.

---

The [className property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) maps to the [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) which accepts a **space-separated list** of class names.

```
class="foo bar"
```

In a selector, when writing multiple selectors (be they type selectors, class selectors, attribute selectors, other selectors, or a mix of any of the above) which target the same element, they are simply mashed together.

```
.foo.bar
```

In short: **Different language = Different syntax**.